# Angular - Dependent Select Dropdown is not refreshing initial data on the list

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am implementing select dependent dropdown. I have two models:

- vehicle_models
- vehicle_makes

One vehicle make have many models:

Then this api JSON response:

```js
{
  "message": "Vehicle Make Successfully Retrieved.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "vehiclemakes": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Acura",
        "code": "ACURA",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "BMW",
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Renault",
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Toyota",
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Volvo",
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Volkswagen",
      }
    ]
  }
}


{
  "message": "Vehicle Model Successfully Retrieved.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "vehiclemodels": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "- 2.2CL",
        "make_id": 1,
        "vehiclemake": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Acura",
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "100",
        "make_id": 6,
        "vehiclemake": {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "v",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

service:

```
   public getAllVehicleModels(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'vehiclemodels/list', this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Component:

```js
vehicletypes!: any[];
vehiclemakes!: any[];
vehiclemodels!: any[];
make_id!: '';
model_id!: '';

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadAllParameters();
  this.loadVehicleMakeData(event);
  this.loadVehicleModelData(event);
  this.createVehicle();
}

createVehicle() {
  this.createForm = this.fb.group({
    vehicle_make_id: ['', [Validators.required]],
    vehicle_model_id: ['', [Validators.required]]
  });
}

loadAllParameters() {
  this.vehicleService.getVehicleParameters().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.vehiclemakes = data.results.vehiclemakes;
      this.vehiclemodels = data.results.vehiclemodels;
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
    }
  );
}

loadVehicleMakeData(event: any) {
  if (event) {
    this.make_id = event.id;
  } else {
    this.make_id = '';
  }
  this.vehicleModelService.getVehicleModelsByMake(this.make_id).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.vehiclemodels = data.results.vehiclemodels;
    }
  );
}
loadVehicleModelData(event: any) {
  if (event) {
    this.model_id = event.id;
  } else {
    this.model_id = '';
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="vehicle_make_id">Vehicle Make:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <ng-select [items]="vehiclemakes" (change)="loadVehicleMakeData($event)" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select Vehicle Make" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" required formControlName="vehicle_make_id">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="vehicle_model_id">Vehicle Model:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <ng-select [items]="vehiclemodels" (change)="loadVehicleModelData($event)" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select Vehicle Model" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" required formControlName="vehicle_model_id">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: dependent dropdown]

I expect that when user selects Vehicle Make, it should load the corresponding Vehicle Model. This is working.

Where I have issue is that when the user selects any the loaded Vehicle Model, then goes back to Vehicle Make to select another Make. At this point the initial Vehicle Model onChange still remains, it's not cleared.

How do I make Vehicle Make onChange to first clear everything in Vehicle Model before it populates it with fresh data?

Thanks

Comment: if you set the form control `vehicle_model_id` to null?

Comment: @amnah - I did this   vehicle_model_id: ['NULL', [Validators.required]]   but the value still remain instead of refreshing

Comment: I added an answer with stackblitz @user11352561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, you can do this on loadVehicleMakeData, so every time you change the make, it will reset the model.

```
loadVehicleMakeData(event: any) {
    this.form.patchValue({vehicle_model_id: null});
  }
```

Take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6gnkrr-bigtva?file=src%2Fbindings-nested-example.component.ts). I hard coded the data you shared in your answer.

Comment: Everything was going fine until when I did:   this.vehiclemodels = this.vehicleModelService.getAllVehicleModels.filter((item: any) => {     I got this error:   Property 'filter' does not exist on type '(vehiclemodelId: any) => Observable<any>'.

Comment: Since I'm getting the data from endpoint through the     public getAllVehicleModels(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'vehiclemodels/list', this.httpOptions);
    }     service

Comment: You can skip this part. I did this on array because i didn't have the http call. But you mentioned that on selecting 'make' the corresponding 'model' is being updated? You can use the same logic. Or. You can use .pipe(filter((item:any=>{}) (sorry i am on phone)

Comment: I think there should be a way to add     .filter    in this service:       public getAllVehicleModels(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'vehiclemodels/list', this.httpOptions);
  }

Comment: you can maybe use https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter

Comment: public getAllVehicleModels(): Observable<any> { return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'vehiclemodels/list', this.httpOptions).pipe(filter((data:any) => {}))
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can observe one of your form fields by subscribing to it (in onInit), like this:

```js
this.createForm.get("vehicle_make_id").valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
   this.resetModel()
})
```

Then you need to patch the form value for 'vehicle_model_id':

```js
resetModel(): void {
  this.createForm.patchValue({
    vehicle_model_id: null
  })
}
```

One of the major reasons to use reactive forms is to keep your html clean, so I would get rid of your (change) events and just observe the form fields instead. It will keep your code clean, readable and easy to test.

Comment: @G3AR7B3A7 - When I added this to OnInit       this.createForm.get("vehicle_make_id").valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.resetModel()
   });     I got this error:      Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: Either ensure the compiler that the FormGroup will always be assigned a value in the declaration with ! (e.g.: createForm!: FormGroup) or do a nullcheck on the form object before subscribing to it ... (e.g.: if(this.createForm) { this.createform.get .... }

Comment: I did createForm!: FormGroup,  yet the error is there. That's just the only thing

Comment: Try this: this.createForm.get("vehicle_make_id")!.valueChanges.subscribe(() => { this.resetModel() }) ... Is that the null value you refer to? I'm just guessing, I would have to see the whole error log. Make sure you observe the FormControl after you initialize the FormGroup (with this.createVehicle() in your case).